# FizzBuzz using integers from file in C

Tags: c

The program is supposed to take 3 integers from a file: x, y and n. It then prints a fizzbuzz using x and y instead of 3 and 5, starting at 1 and ending at n. It is meant to do this for each line of the file. However, when run the program just goes in an infinite loop. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int x, y, n, i;
    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, file)) {
        scanf(line, "%d", &x);
        scanf(line, "%d", &y);
        scanf(line, "%d", &n);

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if ((i % x == 0) && (i % y == 0)) {
                printf("FB ");
            } else
            if (i % x == 0) {
                printf("F ");
            } else
            if (i % y == 0) {
                printf("B ");
            } else {
                printf("%d", i);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the input file you use?

Comment: It's a text file consisting of "3 5 25", when I use multiple lines the same thing seems to happen

Comment: You should get compiler warnings about your `scanf` lines... always pay attention to compiler messages

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: always check the value in `argc` before accessing anything in `argv[]` beyond `argv[0]` to assure the command line parameter actually exists

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers make code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.   The 'magic' number in the code is 1034.  Suggest using #define to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  For the posted code, the compiler raises a warning about the unused parameter `argc`.

Comment: this kind of line: `scanf(line, "%d", &x);` is not correct.   The `scanf()` function is for reading from stdin.  suggest using `sscanf()` which is for reading from a local buffer. (which is what the posted code is trying to do.)   Strongly suggest reading/understanding the man page for each system function being called by your program.

Comment: when calling any of the `scan` family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  for the calls in the code, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Comment: for readabiliy and understandability by us humans, 1) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line  2) Please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.,  It also greatly helps to use meaningful variable names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sscanf` instead of `scanf`. `scanf` waits for user from standard input. `sscanf` reads input from the string (`const char *`) passed as the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You read the integers with `scanf` instead of `sscanf`.  The format string is the line you got from the file, the parsing will not succeed, but the `scanf` will read from `stdin` to attempt to match the format string. So your program is not running an infinite loop, it is waiting for your input.  If you type any character different from the file contents and a linefeed, `scanf()` will return `0`, and the variables `x`, `y` and `n` will stay uninitialized.  The program may output many numbers in a seemingly infinite loop (again) if `n` happens to be large and positive and none of `x` and `y` happen to be `0`.

You should instead do this:

```
if (sscanf(line, "%d%d%d", &x, &y, &n) != 3) {
    printf("invalid input\n");
    continue;
}
```

Also note that your *normal* printf should have a trailing space for numbers to be correctly separated:

```
printf("%d ", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

1. compiles cleanly
2. incorporates error checking
3. performs the desired operation
4. incorporates the comments about problems in the code
5. exits when EOF is reached

I have also added some commentary about each part of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <errno.h>   // errno
#include <string.h>  // strerror()

#define MAX_LINE_LEN (1024)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( 2 != argc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line parameters

    FILE *file = NULL;
    if( NULL == ( file = fopen(argv[1], "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        fprintf( stderr, "fopen fail to open %s for input due to: %s\n", argv[1], strerror( errno ) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int x;
    int y;
    int n;

    char line[ MAX_LINE_LEN ];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        if( 3 != sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &x, %y, %n) )
        {
            perror( "sscanf failed" );
            fclose( file );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, sscanf successful

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if ((i % x == 0) && (i % y == 0))
            {
                printf("FB ");
            }

            else if (i % x == 0)
            {
                printf("F ");
            }

            else if (i % y == 0)
            {
                printf("B ");
            }

            else
            {
                printf("%d ", i);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
} // end function: main
```

Comment: @chqrlie,  Your right, my error.  I'll edit the posted answer

Comment: Returning `0` from `main()` may have become implicit since C99, it is still considered good style to do it.

Comment: @chqrlie,  thanks for proof reading the answer.  as it is, I also forgot to add a call to `fclose()` before exiting the main() function.